# Django admin search, sentence search

Tags: django, search, admin, django-queryset

I've got some problems with the admin search and was wondering if anyone had any suggestion/pointers what I'm doing wrong?

In admin search_fields i'm doing this search_fields = ['games_played', 'dxdiag',] and it works fine for games_played but dxdiag is a dxdiag with certain data retrieved from and the turned into JSON string.

What I want to do is be able to search for more then one word, for example "windows xp" (with the " to tell that there is more then one word) and to do this I override the queryset, but it doesn't work.
When I search for "windows xp" then I get "0 results (13 total)" (13 of the 15 posts have windows xp in them) and no posts are shown. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly or am I just forgetting something?

```
class AdminUserData(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['games_played', 'dxdiag',] #Search field at top

def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(AdminUserData, self).queryset(request)

    if request.GET:
        query = request.GET.get('q')

        if query == None:
            return qs

        data = query.split(' ')

        begin = []
        end = []

        if data == None:
            return qs

        for item in data:
            if item.startswith("'"):
                begin.append(item[1:])
            if item.endswith("'"):
                end.append(item[:-1])

        if len(begin) == 0 or len(end) == 0:
            return qs

        result = []
        for i in xrange(0, len(begin)):
            if begin[i][:-1] == end[i][1:]:
                result.append(begin[i][:-1])
            else:
                result.append(begin[i] + ' ' + end[i])

        for i in xrange(0, len(result)):
            qs = qs.filter(dxdiag__icontains=result[i])

    print qs #prints all user that has a dxdiag with "windows xp"  
    return qs
```